# flex justify-content centre

Tags: css, flexbox, centering

I'm creating a mobile first site and I'm trying to use flex to center my headers. I want the the children of the container to be centered. I've also tried without using flex by setting the margins of the children to auto but that doesn't seem to center it either. Where am I going wrong?

**The Code**

```css
.footer__social {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.footer__social--h1 {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer__social">    
  <img class="footer__social--h1" alt="Heading"     src="Images/footer__social--h1.png"/>
  <img class="footer__social--h2" alt="Sub heading" src="Images/footer__social--h2.png"/>
  <div class="footer__social--Icons"> <!-- ICONS -->
    <img class="footer__social--Icons-twitter" alt="Twitter" src="Images/footer__social--icons-twitter.png"/>
    <img class="footer__social--Icons-facebook" alt="Facebook" src="Images/footer__social--icons-facebook.png"/>
    <img class="footer__social--Icons-Instagram" alt="Instagram" src="Images/footer__social--icons-instagram.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: You say headers but the code says footers...huh?

Comment: sorry, i should have been more clear, its the headers of the footer (h1, h2). They are however in the form of images as I extracted from a psd

Comment: So something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/rch0x1wp/ ? BTW...images instead of text...bad idea generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use column, then you need  `align-items:center;`

```css
.footer__social {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}
.footer__social--h1 {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer__social">    
  <img class="footer__social--h1" alt="Heading"     src="Images/footer__social--h1.png"/>
  <img class="footer__social--h2" alt="Sub heading" src="Images/footer__social--h2.png"/>
  <div class="footer__social--Icons"> <!-- ICONS -->
    <img class="footer__social--Icons-twitter" alt="Twitter" src="Images/footer__social--icons-twitter.png"/>
    <img class="footer__social--Icons-facebook" alt="Facebook" src="Images/footer__social--icons-facebook.png"/>
    <img class="footer__social--Icons-Instagram" alt="Instagram" src="Images/footer__social--icons-instagram.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

else , margin auto on childs , h1 for demo here

```css
.footer__social {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.footer__social--h1 {
  width: 25%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer__social">    
  <img class="footer__social--h1" alt="Heading"     src="Images/footer__social--h1.png"/>
  <img class="footer__social--h2" alt="Sub heading" src="Images/footer__social--h2.png"/>
  <div class="footer__social--Icons"> <!-- ICONS -->
    <img class="footer__social--Icons-twitter" alt="Twitter" src="Images/footer__social--icons-twitter.png"/>
    <img class="footer__social--Icons-facebook" alt="Facebook" src="Images/footer__social--icons-facebook.png"/>
    <img class="footer__social--Icons-Instagram" alt="Instagram" src="Images/footer__social--icons-instagram.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using images for heading text...actual text that can be read by screenreaders and indexed by Google is much preferred.

However, I think you want something like this:

```css
.footer__social {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 50%;
  /* or whatever */
  text-align: center;
}
.icons {
  margin-top: auto;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer__social">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/nightlife-q-c-150-40-1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/technics-q-c-150-30-3.jpg" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad consequuntur, fugit quaerat? Ullam, molestias, illum.</p>
  <div class="icons">
    <!-- ICONS -->
    <img class="footer__social--Icons-twitter" alt="Twitter" src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-40-40-6.jpg" />
    <img class="footer__social--Icons-facebook" alt="Facebook" src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-40-40-6.jpg" />
    <img class="footer__social--Icons-Instagram" alt="Instagram" src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-40-40-6.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```